# Await on findOne returns not found (404) all the time

Tags: node.js, async-await, http-status-code-404, koa

the below code returns not found (404) all the time. But the console logs the data as expected.
I am using Node, Koa, and Mongoose.

the server.js

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const bodyparser = require('koa-bodyparser');
const UserRoutes = require('./router/user.routes');
const TrustRoutes = require('./router/trust.routes');
const auth = require('./middleware/auth');
const app = new Koa();

require('dotenv').config();
require('./db');

app.use(bodyparser());

app.use(auth);

app.use(
   TrustRoutes.routes()
).use(TrustRoutes.allowedMethods());

app.use(
   UserRoutes.routes()
).use(UserRoutes.allowedMethods());

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

trust.routes.js

```
const router = new Router({
    prefix: '/trust'
});


router.get('/:trustId', async (ctx,next) => {
    let id = ctx.params.trustId;
    let trust = await Trust.findById(id);
    console.log(trust);
    ctx.response.body = {
        status: true,
        message: 'Trust info',
        data: trust
    };
    console.log('trust info');
    next();
});

module.exports = router
```

the console logs the below details

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("61ed34100ebd7c8fbdbef596"),
  name: 'new trust',
  description: 'match',
  contact: { email: 'gmail@gmail.com', phone: '90334' },
  isActive: true,
  createdAt: 2022-01-23T10:55:12.866Z,
  updatedAt: 2022-01-23T10:55:12.866Z,
  __v: 0
}
trust info
```

and the middleware (I suspect in here)

```
require('dotenv').config();
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const User = require("../models/user")

const except = [
    '/user/login'
];

const verifyToken = async (ctx, next) => {

if (except.indexOf(ctx.request.path) >= 0) return next();

let  token = (
    ctx.request.body.token || ctx.request.query.token ||
    ctx.request.headers["authorization"]
);

if (!token) {
    ctx.response.status = 403;
    ctx.body = {
        status: false,
        message: 'Unauthorized'
    }
    return;
}
token = token.replace(/^Bearer\s+/,'');
try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_KEY);
    const user = await User.findOne({
        email: decoded.username
    },{password: 0});
    ctx.request.user = user;
} catch (err) {
    ctx.response.status = 403;
    ctx.body = {
        status: false,
        message: 'Unauthorized'
    }
    return;
}
next();
};
module.exports = verifyToken;
```

I know that something in here is not correct but hard to understand since it's my first time on these async and koa with middleware please help me out on this.

the postman
[image]

Comment: The "Not Found" error that you describe seems unrelated to the code you've posted.

Comment: I have attached a postman screenshot Please check, Thanks @jsejcksn

Comment: I answered your question according to the information you posted, but you keep editing your question to add new information. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), such that anyone with only Node.js and npm installed can reproduce the issue from scratch. You'll need to include all source files necessary to run the project. If you have a link to a GitHub repository, that might help someone who wants to answer your question.

Comment: How is your router used/setup in your app?

Comment: the route file : router/trust.routes.js and the route registered in server.js as app.use(
  TrustRoutes.routes()
).use(TrustRoutes.allowedMethods()); @eol

Comment: Can you edit your question and show how you export/import the router?

Comment: Added the server.js and the middleware (i suspect) @eol to be frank i dont know how to add this external middleware into the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't export anything from your router-file. In order to use

```
app
.use(TrustRoutes.routes())
.use(TrustRoutes.allowedMethods());
```

you need to export the koa-router from the `TrustRoutes`-file:

```
const router = new Router({
    prefix: '/trust'
});

router.get('/:trustId', async (ctx,next) => {
    // ...
});

module.exports = router;
```

Apart from this when using `async` handlers, you need to either return next or await (see https://github.com/ZijianHe/koa-router/issues/476):

```
router.get('/:trustId', async (ctx,next) => {
        // ...
    return next(); // or await next();
});
```

Comment: that's my bad. I have the piece of my code in the file. But missed adding it. I got a clue. When I tried with the line commented app.use(auth);. It works. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Since i can see the console logs. we could confirm the method being called in the route.

Comment: adding return next(); on the middleware solved the issue. Thanks Eol.

Comment: Solved a related issue for me after days of debugging.

Answer (score 2):

I missed to have `return next()` in auth js the middleware.
After updating it `next();` to `return next()` it works.

```
const verifyToken = async (ctx, next) => {
    .....
    return next();
};
```

Comment: Solved a related issue for me after days of debugging.